# How to Angular CLI commands and running ng add --help and oops

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

#### Problem:

An `unhandled` exception occurred: Unable to locate a `workspace` file for `workspace` path.

See "C:\Users\KELVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-f6Wqh8\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: You need to be inside of an Angular project to run `ng add --help`. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16241#issuecomment-556059075).

Comment: Taking a look at the contents of `C:\Users\KELVIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-f6Wqh8\angular-errors.log` will probably be helpful; like the message says, it contains "further details". Even if you can't make sense of those logs, adding them to the question can help us help you.

Comment: Grateful for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to use Angular CLI commands outside of an Angular CLI generated project. First create a new project `ng new test-app` then cd into it `cd test-app`. Now you can run secondary commands!

If you're learning the CLI, I'd highly recommend keeping a link to the documentation handy. For example, the `ng add --help` will give you a less robust list that is found on their doc page here: https://angular.io/cli/add